# manage FirstResponder in subclass of NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, macos, first-responder

I have a `TextViewController` which is a subclass of `NSViewController` which controls a View containing a `NSTextView`

I attach an instance of `TextViewController` to an existing view with the following code

```
TextViewController *textViewer;
```

...

```
[[self view] addSubview:[textViewer view]]; // embed new TextView in our host view
[[textViewer view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];  // resize the controller's view to the host size
textViewer.delegate = self;
[split.window makeFirstResponder:textViewer];
```

This works quite well, and the `TextViewController` traps the `keyDown` Event to perform various actions.

I wanted to allow users to select text in the `NSTextView` to copy to clipboard.
Unfortunately clicking in the `NSTextView` makes this the `FirstResponder` and stops `TextViewController` from responding to key presses.

I can force the FirstResponder back to my TextViewController, but this seems like a kludge.

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self.view.window makeFirstResponder:self];
}
```

I know I could subclass `NSTextView` to trap the keyDown Event, but this doesn't seem much better.

I am sure there must be a more elegant way of doing this.

I added a subclass of NSTextView which just passes the keyDown to the controller

```
@protocol MyTextViewDelegate
- (BOOL)keyPressedInTextView:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
@end

@interface MyTextView : NSTextView
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSObject <MyTextViewDelegate> *delegate;
@end
```

...

```
@implementation MyTextView
@synthesize delegate;
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(keyPressedInTextView:)]) {
        if([self.delegate keyPressedInTextView:theEvent])
            return;
        }
    [super keyDown:theEvent];
}
@end
```

Comment: What actions does `[TextViewController keyDown]` perform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclassing `NSTextView` sounds like the best solution for the problem you described. You want a text view that behaves like normal to select, copy, Cmd-A, etc. except that it also responds to special key presses you've defined. This is a standard use of a subclass. Trying to have the view controller handle things by playing games with the first responder will give you problems in various edge cases like the one you discovered.

Comment: I was probably a mistake making a View Controller the FirstResponder, so I added a subclass of NSView. I expected this would also get the kestrokes from its enclosed NSTextView, but this did not work, so I added a subclass of NSTextView